# Replace spaces, tabs and carriage returns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, replace

I am working with SQL developer with Oracle 11g. I have a query that looks something along the lines of this;

```
SELECT [column], [column], [column],...... rs.notes
FROM [table], [table], [table]............ return_sku rs
WHERE [conditions] AND [conditions] AND [conditions]
```

In the `return_sku` column there are tabs, spaces, and newlines (I believe this is a carriage return?) I need to make all of these spaces, carriage returns and tabs disappear when I run my query.

I am fairly new to SQL, but the most popular search result I found is the REPLACE function. I have absolutely no idea how to use this, as I've tried this in many different ways with no result. I've tried the following;

```
SELECT [column], [column], [column],...... REPLACE(rs.notes, Char(10), '')
FROM [table], [table], [table]............ return_sku rs
WHERE [conditions] AND [conditions] AND [conditions]
```

This gives the error message:

```
ORA-00904: "RS"."NOTES": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 531
```

How do I use this function correctly?

Comment: The error suggests your `return_sku` table does not have a `notes` column; or you've lost the alias, or you have the table and its alias in a subquery. The trouble with retyping code like this, rather than showing something that actually demonstrates the behaviour, is that you can lose the actual problem along the way, particularly if it's a typo. Maybe you can get the same error by only selecting from that one table, and can show us the table definition. It should be `chr(10)`, incidentally, not `char(10)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Oracle if you just want to remove a character you can omit the third argument of the replace call and the function for character codes is chr(), not char().

So your line would be `SELECT ... replace(rs.notes,chr(10)) ...`

Comment: I totally overlooked this, as I was in the middle of a bunch of different projects and found the answer yet completely forgot that I asked it here. Thank you very much for your response. This is actually what I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't address the ORA-00904, which I suspect is a typo, but can't really tell without seeing the real code. But if you need to strip out several characters, you can do a nested replace:

```
with return_sku as (
    select 'This is '||chr(9)|| ' a split'||chr(10)||chr(13)||'line' as notes
    from dual
)
select replace(replace(replace(replace(rs.notes, chr(10)), chr(13)), chr(9)), ' ')
from return_sku rs;

REPLACE(REPLACE(
----------------
Thisisasplitline
```

... but a [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm) might be more manageable, if possibly a little more costly:

```
with return_sku as (
    select 'This is '||chr(9)|| ' a split'||chr(10)||chr(13)||'line' as notes
    from dual
)
select regexp_replace(rs.notes, '[ '||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(9)||']')
from return_sku rs;

REGEXP_REPLACE(R
----------------
Thisisasplitline
```

I've included both line feed (`chr(10)`) and carriage return (`chr(13)`) in both; might be overkill. But if you do want to remove any whitespace, this gets even simpler:

```
select regexp_replace(rs.notes, '\s') ...
```

or the Posix version:

```
select regexp_replace(rs.notes, '[[:space:]]') ...
```

As @randcd pointed out, if the third argument to `replace` or `regexp_replace` is null (or an empty string, which is the same as null in Oracle) then you don't need to supply it.

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I totally overlooked this, as I was in the middle of a bunch of different projects and found the answer yet completely forgot that I asked it here. Thank you very much for your response.